# Shopify - Suppress Homepage Element

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to suppress a promotional banner on the homepage only within Shopify.

I'd like it to be presented on ALL pages with the exception of the homepage.

Can I do that in the theme liquid, and if so, how do you I go about doing it?

It's the green bar right below the top navigation.

```
www.surefit.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In you main.scss (or theme/style depend of your theme) you can insert :

```
.template-index .promotional-bar { display:none !Important;}
```